# Trigger JavaScript Anchor Function (Without User Clicking on it)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where users see this anchor...

```
<a href="javascript:launchSomething("1", "2", "1")">Test</a>
```

Is it possible to execute/call `launchSomething(.....)` function without having the user to click it? If the params were fixed values then I could just do something like ...

```
//on document.ready() {
//  launchSomething( .... );  
//}
```

but the web page is generated dynamically and these params change too so what do I need to do to trigger it automatically once the web page has loaded?

thanks for help.

UPDATE

I have just got the markup changed to

```
<a class="click1" href="javascript:launchSomething('1', '2', '1')">Test</a>
```

so it always has a class "click1"

Comment: That is no valid HTML, btw. Do you generate that page yourself?

Comment: there is php foreach loop ... eg. `foreach($rows as $row) { launchsomething($row[id]); } `

Comment: @Bergi - no but I can get the HTML markup changed on request ...

Comment: @user1421214: Then file a bunch of requests: 1) Do escape the quotes properly 2) Do not use `javascript:`-urls - if use inline handler, use the `onclick` attribute 3) Do not use inline handlers at all, separate content from behaviour… - Just follow best practises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by dynamically generating an attribute for your links:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<a class="mylink" data-id=\''.$row['id'].'\'>Test </a>'; 
}
```

You can then bind this as the click handler for your link:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(){
    launchSomething($(this).data('id'));
});
```

To invoke the handler for a specific link, you could use:

```
$('.mylink[data-id="someID"]').click();
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that there is a provision to have more than one launchSomething() function ... something like `foreach($rows as $row) { echo '<a launchsomething('.$row['id'].')Test </a>'; }` ... however most of the times its just one entry of this on the page... so ur suggestion to have it declared in the function doesnt seem to fit my requirements ... i do understand the point you made. thx

Comment: @user1421214 Well what parameters do you want to use in the invocation at page load?

Comment: erm ... e.g. if the data array looked like  $launch_params = array( array("id" => 2, "parentid" => 10, "pageid" => 3), array("id" => 8, "parentid" => 50, "pageid" => 5) ); `.... we will always call function with very first set of params ... makes any sense? like I said users can click on this links too to invoke that function ... but automatically we just want to invoke the very first one.

Comment: I can see your edit and got it ... seems like it will work just fine .. just need to test and I get back to you how it goes ... cheers asad!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you trust enough the code (you probably should as you generate it), you could use this :

```
eval($('a[href^="javascript:launchSomething("]').attr('href').slice(11));
```

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/WP9aE/)

Notes :

- you'll see I fixed the lack of quote escaping in your HTML
- my first idea, based on jQuery trigger function, doesn't work as it work only with callback added by jQuery.

Comment: That won't actually work, since the link has no click event handlers bound.

Comment: @Asad I saw that. I made another (tested) version

Comment: hi - yes trust the code but if you suggest any markup changes like adding a class to anchor would that make it any difference (so that we don't have to use eval()) ??

Comment: The eval is used to execute the javascript in the href, not to find the element. There is no problem here in using eval.